# Creating a separator

Tags: html, css

What i want to accomplish is create the line under latest news in one div without images. I thought about borders but i don't see how it could be done like this. I tried with pseudoelements(:before, :after) but they seem to mees up the layout in very weird ways. Anybody got an ideea? Or at least if it can't be done how i want i must know

```
<div id="footer">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
                <h4>Latest News</h4>
                <p>
                    Consectetur adipisci. Belit, sed quia
                </p>
                <hr>
                <p>
                    Non numquam eius modi tempora
                </p>
                <hr>
                <p>
                    Incidunt, ut labore et dolore ater
                </p>
                <hr>
                <p>
                    Magnam aliquam quaerat dolores.
                </p>
                <hr>
                <br>
                <h4> Subscribe Via Email </h4>
            </div>
      </div> 
</div>
```

This is where i intend to put it. As you may have figured i use the bootstrap 3 framework

Comment: okay, so where's the CSS that you've tried so far?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use a :before or :after element.

```
h1 {
  position: relative;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #bbb;
}

h1:before {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -3px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 5px;
  display: block;
  content: "";
  background-color: #219fd1;
}
```

This should get you close enough.

Here is a quick demo: http://jsbin.com/IfEzeDUT/1/edit?html,css,output

Comment: The precise color that the op was looking for is `#219fd1`

Comment: I've updated it... but I like to leave a little for OP to do. =)

Comment: this is the closest to what i was trying to acomplish, thanks alot man. here is my updated demo

http://jsbin.com/IfEzeDUT/5/edit?html,css,output

what i also want to know is how are the :before and :after elements "seen" by the browser. do they have their own box or something?

Comment: I think of them, by default, as span elements inside the element they're applied to `:before` the content begins or `:after` the content ends. You can do whatever you want to them, though. I think the important thing is to realize is they're **children** of the element, **not** siblings.

Answer (score 1):

Can simply use a border-bottom to set them as separator.
http://jsfiddle.net/notme/4V95c/

```
.container {
    background-color:black;
    color: white;
}

p {
    border-bottom: 1px dotted white;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0 20px;
}

h4 {
    border-bottom: 2px solid blue;
    display:inline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/OTUzUla/2/edit)

[image]

```
.col-sm-3 h4{
  color:#f6f6f6;
  position:relative;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #858686;
  padding:15px 0;
  margin:0;
}
.col-sm-3 h4:after{
  content:" ";
  position:absolute;
  height:4px;
  width:65px;
  bottom:-2px;
  left:0px;
  background:#219FD1;
}
/* instead of <hr> */
.col-sm-3 > p{
  margin:0;
  padding: 10px 0;
  border-bottom:1px dotted #858686;
}
```